# the cat fixes everything with a load of weird machines

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A British wrote in an American forum:
> I’m going to be quite mean now and spoil the ending for him.
> Just as their mother is about to return home **the cat fixes everything with a load of weird machines**, but he does come back.

The "cat" here appears to refer to "the person". But what does the phrase "the cat fixes everything with a load of weird machines" mean? Does it mean the person makes every effort to make his room tidy so that his mother will find nothing wrong with him?

Comment: There's no idiomatic meaning here. It means the cat fixes everything with a load of weird machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question; we need to know the story you are talking about. I’m going to make a reasonable assumption that it is The Cat in the Hat by Dr. Seuss.

This is a fantasy story, and the meaning is literal. An actual cat uses machines to repair the house. Although the cat does have human-like qualities, it is still a cat in the story.